# GitLab merge request API + merge_status

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

We're trying to use the GitLab API to automate the merge request lifecycle based on the movement of Jira tickets.

Using the `/merge_requests` endpoint, I can see the `merge_status` field which seems to contain one of the following values: `unchecked`, `can_be_merged`, `cannot_be_merged`, `cannot_be_merged_recheck`, or `checking`.

**Question 1:** is there any documentation on what the individual status values mean, and what can trigger these being returned?

I can also see the use of the `with_merge_status_recheck` [option]https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) (added in 13.0) which controls how the `merge_status` field is updated/reported.

The API documentation states:

> - [Introduced](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29984) in GitLab 12.8, the mergeability ( `merge_status` ) of each merge request is checked asynchronously when a request is made to this endpoint. Poll this API endpoint to get updated status. This affects the `has_conflicts` property as it is dependent on the `merge_status` . It returns `false` unless `merge_status` is `cannot_be_merged` .
> - [Introduced](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/31890) in GitLab 13.0, listing merge requests may not proactively update `merge_status` (which also affects the `has_conflicts` ), as this can be an expensive operation. If you need the value of these fields from this endpoint, set the `with_merge_status_recheck` parameter to `true` in the query.

And the parameter option says:

> `with_merge_status_recheck` -- If `true` , this projection requests (but does not guarantee) that the `merge_status` field be recalculated asynchronously. Default is `false` .

**Question 2:** If I call `GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:project_id/merge_requests/:id?with_merge_status_recheck=true`, what is the expected outcome? The parameter documentation indicates that `with_merge_status_recheck` initiates an asynchronous calculation, but how do I know when the value of `merge_status` is accurate, and I can rely on it?

I've tried timing a call with `with_merge_status_recheck=true`, and `=false`, and there are no obvious performance deviations that can indicate what's happening.